# How do I lookup configMap values to build k8s manifest using ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd, gitops

I'm using ArgoCD for gitops deployments right now and I have k8s manifest files that require configMap values to be built (via helm right now).  However, ArgoCD does not allow me to use helm lookup feature so I can't have that in my helm chart.

I have a helm chart that uses helm lookup to pull values from a configMap to build a k8s manifest file (pretty common).  The problem is that argocd does not allow me to use the helm lookup functionality when it is deploying the helm chart.  Has anyone come across this situation where you need to build a manifest file using values in a configMap while using ArgoCD?  How did you accomplish that?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What helm lookup feature are you referring to? I know flux has a feature as you described, but I wasn't aware vanilla helm did as well.

Comment: helm3 added it.  Here is an example of how to do it in helm.  (lookup "v1" "Namespace" "" "mynamespace").metadata.annotations.  Check out https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/

Comment: Ah, thanks, I wasn't aware of this feature. It is a bit different than the feature in flux, which uses a configmap in the cluster as helm values

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a well-known issue for ArgoCD to work with helm, I think the below thread will be helpful for you.
https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/5202